# complex logical operation

Tags: logic

Given this logical operation :

(A AND B) OR (C AND D)

Is there a way to write a similar expression without using any parentheses and giving the same result ? Usage of logical operators AND, OR, NOT are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
A and B or C and D
```

In most programming languages, `and` is taken to have higher precedence than `or` (this stems from the equivalence of `and` and `or` to `*` and `+`, respectively).

Of course, if your original expression had been:

```
(A or B) and (C or D)
```

you couldn't simply remove the parentheses.  In this instance, you'd have to "multiply out" the factors:

```
A and C or B and C or A and D or B and D
```

Comment: In most programming languages that's the case. Unfortunately I was stuck with a program that has some filters that you can combine with AND / OR. When trying 4 different conditions linked with logical operations as shown in my question, it seems like the program applies them "linearly", applying the first one, and then applying the result to the second one and so on. So if for instance I have A=TRUE, B=TRUE, C=FALSE, D=FALSE, I would like to have a result of TRUE, but the program doesn't show me any entry which makes me think that it returns FALSE.

Comment: That would make sense if the programs starts by applying the operations one after another. So let's say we have A=TRUE, B=TRUE, C=FALSE, D=FALSE. Then the intermediate results are :
1. TRUE and TRUE = TRUE 
2. TRUE or FALSE = TRUE
3. TRUE and FALSE = FALSE which is the final result.

Comment: I would like to add a correction for the word `in most programming languages`. The Logical AND has a higher precedence in languages only that support overloading (This excludes Java, C and includes C++ as per wiki). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Zedai: AND has higher precedence than OR in all the languages you listed.  Try `true && false || true`.

Comment: I fail to see why you want the expression without the parens.  The expression is more clear to more audiences with them.

Answer (score 1):

How about `A AND B OR C AND D`? It's the same because `AND` takes precedence over `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put any parentheses, it is the same...

Answer (score 0):

It can be written in two ways

1. A & B | C & D
2. Type as it is mentioned in question just remove the parenthesis it will show the same result.

We can use `&` for `AND` to multiply and `|` for `OR` to divide. Also simply you can write them without any parenthesis

Comment: The same answers are already given, post an answer only if you can suggest anything that has not been suggested yet.